# What is the logic behind needing to convert a 1D array to 2D to concatenate?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

In order to concatenate a 1D array to a 2D array, the following fix is suggested:

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3])
B = np.array([[4, 5],[6,7],[8,9]])

# np.hstack((A,B)) 
# throws "ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions"

np.hstack((A[:, None],B)) #works
```

Could someone please explain the logic behind this? (with link?)

Coming from a matlab background, this requirement is unintuitive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason for this difference between numpy and MATLAB is a difference in philosophy and design.

The numpy package is designed with a focus more towards integrating with the python programming language and dealing with standard types of variables that are found in the python programming language.  MATLAB, on the other hand, is designed around matrices.

The basic type of data in MATLAB is the matrix, so that even what looks like a floating point number is really a 1 x 1 matrix.  You can see evidence [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/empty-matrices-scalars-and-vectors.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) that MATLAB is designed with the matrix as its foundational type.

In numpy, however, the arrays that are used are closer cousins to single-dimensional and multidimensional arrays in the python programming language.  So numpy provides relatively generic methods like `concatenate` and `split` that support an argument defining which axis of a multidimensional array they should operate on.  In recent enough versions (since 1.10), there is also the `stack` method that can add a dimension as it concatenates.  The page [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html) is the reference for a variety of array manipulation methods in version 1.11, including the three I've mentioned and the `hstack` and `column_stack` methods.

By the way, there are other ways to get the same result matrix.  Two possibilities that might appeal a little more to MATLAB users are

```
np.hstack((np.atleast_2d(A).T, B))
```

and

```
np.hstack((A.reshape([A.size,1]), B))
```

Also, it is technically possible to extract the columns from `B` as 1-dimensional arrays and build the matrix you want to build by stacking together 1-D arrays.  With older versions of numpy, combining the 1-D arrays into a matrix uses `vstack` and a transpose.  It could look like this

```
np.vstack([A] + [B[:,j] for j in xrange(B.shape[1])]).T
```

or, if you want to use more numpy array manipulation commands instead of slicing, it could be written

```
np.vstack([A] + [np.squeeze(c) for c in np.hsplit(B, B.shape[1])]).T
```

Answer (score 1):

The document of `hstack()`:

> numpy.hstack(tup)[source] Stack arrays in sequence horizontally
>   (column wise).
>
> Take a sequence of arrays and stack them horizontally to make a single
>   array. Rebuild arrays divided by hsplit.
>
> Parameters:    tup : sequence of ndarrays All arrays must have the same
>   shape along all but the second axis. Returns:  stacked : ndarray The
>   array formed by stacking the given arrays.

**sequence of ndarrays All arrays must have the same shape along all but the second axis.**

`A[:, None]` creates a new array with shape `(3, 1)`, it's a 2D array as `B`, so `hstack()` works.

You can use instead:

```
np.c_[A, B]
np.column_stack((A, B))
```

Comment: In case someone wants the link: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html

Comment: To clarify, I understand that hstack only accepts arrays of a certain shape.  I'm trying to understand WHY there exist separate hstack and column_stack functions that have these restrictions.

Comment: I tried to explain more of what `hstack` and `column_stack` do.

Answer (score 1):

Look at these arrays:

```
In [26]: A
Out[26]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [27]: B
Out[27]: 
array([[4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9]])
In [28]: A[:,None]
Out[28]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])

In [31]: np.concatenate([A[:,None],B],axis=1)
Out[31]: 
array([[1, 4, 5],
       [2, 6, 7],
       [3, 8, 9]])
```

Doesn't it make sense that if you want to join the 3 items of `A` to the 3 rows of `B`, that `A` should also have 3 rows?

The big difference between `numpy` and MATLAB is that in MATLAB everything is 2d (or higher).  In numpy arrays may be 1d, and the difference maters.

Octave comparison:

```
>> A=[1,2,3]
A =

   1   2   3

>> B=[4,5;6,7;8,9]
B =

   4   5
   6   7
   8   9
```

The (1,3) cannot be joined with the (3,2) matrix in either direction:

```
>> cat(1,A,B)
error: cat: dimension mismatch
>> cat(2,A,B)
error: cat: dimension mismatch
```

But it works if I transpose `A`:

```
>> cat(2,A.',B)
ans =

   1   4   5
   2   6   7
   3   8   9
```

So even with the 2d baseline, dimensions still need to line up.

All `hstack` adds to `concatenate` is `atleast_1d`, which doesn't help in this case.  `np.column_stack` makes it 2d and .T, so it works.  I recommend looking at the underlying code for functions like `hstack` and `column_stack` (you may already have the habit from MATLAB).

==================

You comment about the difference between `hstack` and `column_stack`.  They don't have special restrictions, rather they just do different things to adjust the dimensions of their inputs.  Neither is doing anything deep or mysterious.

```
def hstack(tup):
    arrs = [np.atleast_1d(m) for m in tup]
    return np.concatenate(arrs, 0)  # used when A is first
    # return np.concatenate(arrs, 1)  # used when B is first
```

Since both arrays are atleast 1d, the first step adds nothing.  So it's just a matter of trying to do

```
np.concatenate((A,B), axis=0) # or axis=1
```

In either case trying to concatenate a (3,) array to a (3,2) doesn't work - one is 1d, the other 2d.  A (3,1) with a (3,2) does work if you want a (3,3).

```
def column_stack(tup):
    arrays = []
    for v in tup:
        # arr = array(v, copy=False, subok=True)  # already arrays
        if arr.ndim < 2:
            arr = np.array(arr, copy=False, subok=True, ndmin=2).T
        arrays.append(arr)
    return np.concatenate(arrays, 1)
```

In this case `A.ndim<2`; the `array` step turns `A` into a (1,3), and the `T` changes it to (3,1).  That's the same as doing `A[:,None]`.

So it's `np.concatenate` that's imposing the constraints - matching `ndim`, and matching size on the relevant dimension. The `stack` functions are just convenience tools, and don't do anything that you can't do directly.